# Virtual background in Amazon Chime

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I have a question about Amazon Chime.

I created a video chat using chime and was wondering if anyone could give me some tips on how to create a virtual background similar to Zoom's.

I have already used tensorflow and have been able to make a blur effect on another project only that I cannot find a solution to integrate it with chime.

Answer (score 1):

Products such as Snap Camera can create 'virtual cameras'. You can then point Chime to the virtual camera. This means that all the video manipulation is done outside of Chime.

I noticed that *some* virtual cameras do not appear in Chime on the Mac (eg Snap Camera).

Comment: The Chime web client lets you choose a virtual camera, even on Mac OS.

Comment: Okay. But when I run Snap Camera on my Mac, Chime will not let me select it as a camera. @DennisTraub does it work for you? Which virtual camera works for you?

Comment: I’m using OBS with the Virtual Cam add on on the Mac and the browser-based Chime app recognizes everything just fine.

Comment: Aha! So, it works works with _some_ virtual cameras.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I was looking for a solution that concerned both chime and tensorflow in order to manage everything there

Comment: Well, whatever you use, it would need to be _external_ to Chime, and it would need to expose its video stream as a camera device.